# I'm trying to add a custom note into my sql server 2008 db using a php function

Tags: php, sql

Using a dropdown menu, whatever item is selected i would like to add the custom note to the table in my db.

It works fine if i just pass a string like so: ie. QTY OVERRIDE SELECTED

```
if ($this->call_type) sql::query("insert into PWARE.ADS.STACRD (ACCOUNT,ENTRYDATETIME,CATEGORY,NOTE,LOGCODE) VALUES (" . $this->patient->hex .",getdate(),'','QTY OVERRIDE SELECTED'," . login::$hex . ")");
```

But when i use the `$tc` variable i'm not getting the results i would like.

Here's my code:

```
function npc_call_type_status()
        {
        $tc = "($this->call_type == 'PO' ? 'OK - PENDING PO' 
        :($this->call_type == 'IN' ? 'OK - PENDING INS'
        :($this->call_type == 'PI' ? 'OK - PENDING INS/PO'
        :($this->call_type == 'NC' ? 'OK - NO CHANGES'
        : ''))))";  
        if ($this->call_type) sql::query("insert into PWARE.ADS.STACRD (ACCOUNT,ENTRYDATETIME,CATEGORY,NOTE,LOGCODE) VALUES (" . $this->patient->hex .",getdate(),'',".$tc."," . login::$hex . ")");
        }
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What results to do you get? What goes wrong?

Comment: Since `$tc` is a string, you probably need to quote it - `'".$tc."'`. Also why do you have double quotes around the value - `$tc = "(...)";`. Try removing that and the outside `()` -  `$tc = $this->call_type = .... : '')));`

Comment: my error message:  [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'PO'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes from $tc.

```
$tc = ($this->call_type == 'PO' ? 'OK - PENDING PO' 
    :($this->call_type == 'IN' ? 'OK - PENDING INS'
    :($this->call_type == 'PI' ? 'OK - PENDING INS/PO'
    :($this->call_type == 'NC' ? 'OK - NO CHANGES'
    : ''))));
```